# Check if mouse has left specific portion of window

Tags: javascript, windows, mouseevent, document

Is it possible to know if mouse has left specific portion of the window? The values are given below:

```
var cursorX;
var cursorY;
document.onmousemove = function(e){
    cursorX = e.pageX;
    cursorY = e.pageY;
}
document.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
    var dims = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    var top = window.scrollY + dims.top;
    var left = dims.left;
    var width = dims.width;
    var bottom = dims.height;
    if (what condition should be here) {
        console.log('yes mouse has left that portion')
        document.getElementById('div-in-the-end-of-body').style .display = 'none';
    }
});
```

For example values of dims in console log are `ClientRect {top: 155.375, right: 621, bottom: 540.375, left: 313, width: 308…}`

**Here is visual of what I'm trying to achieve.**

[image]

**Edit:** That div at the end of the body has absolute position and it hovers on the images. If I hover at that div images consider mouse has left it and hides the div. This is the reason I want to do it this way.

**Edit # 2: Here is the solution**

```
 elem.onmouseout=function(){
    var dims = this.getBoundingClientRect();
        var top = window.scrollY + dims.top;
        var left = dims.left;
        var width = dims.width;
        var bottom = dims.height;
     if(top > 10 || left > 10 || width > 10 || bottom > 10){
            document.getElementById('div-in-the-end-of-body').style .display = 'none';
     }
 }
```

Comment: You can add the the `mouseout` event directly on that block! Or do you have some other reason to detect it within entire document ??

Comment: you could simply write some events on the divs like ,on mouse enter, on mouse leave , you get simpler codes , with the help of class you came make the same effect on any divs

Comment: with jquery you can get the parents childs and make any change

Comment: Yes that div at the end of the body has absolute position and it hovers on the image. If I hover at that div. image considers mouse has left it. Thats why. And I'm doing everything pure js.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [mouseout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseout.asp) event. Alternatively, you could [capture mouse events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setCapture) as soon as your mouse has entered your specific region.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind event listeners to the "regions" you want to check. As your regions are objects in javascript, there are event listeners built in or you can using obj.call to call functions not belong to the object you created. For instance,

```js
let rects[] // this is your list of regions

for (let rect of rects) {
  rect.onMouseMove((e) => {
    // do something when mouse cursor is moving
  })

  rect.onMouseEnter((e) => {
    // do somthing when mouse cursor enters the area
  })

  rect.onMouseLeave((e) => {
    // do something when mouse cursor exits the area
  })
}
```

Comment: It requires es6 or babel

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've figured out the solution. Here is working code for those who might need.

```
elem.onmouseout=function(){
    var dims = this.getBoundingClientRect();
        var top = window.scrollY + dims.top;
        var left = dims.left;
        var width = dims.width;
        var bottom = dims.height;

     if(top > 10 || left > 10 || width > 10 || bottom > 10){
            console.log('yay!! ship has left the dock')
     }
}
```